# Unable to download excel file using Java

Tags: java, excel, download

I have a requirement to download excel to the excel file on client side using servlet. I am first creating an excel by fetching the values from mysql table and then downloading it. The excel is getting created in the path provided but I am unable to download it. Please find my code below for downloading:

```
String exportFileName = ResourceConstants.EXCEL_FILEPATH+"/"+ResourceConstants.EXCEL_FILENAME;

        FileInputStream inf = null;

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.addHeader("content-disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + exportFileName);
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        final int size = 1024;
        try{
            inf = new FileInputStream(exportFileName);
            response.setContentLength(inf.available());
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            ServletOutputStream os = null;
            os = response.getOutputStream();
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = inf.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            inf.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.error("FileNotFoundException occurred in download excel method!!!"+e.getMessage());
        }
```

Please help me understand if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: I suggest you use POI API for this purpose.

Comment: do have any examples with you, tired that as well and was unable to download it.